# Commands in Dockerfile don't seem to be running

Tags: php, docker, phalcon

So i'm extremely new to docker, and I am having trouble setting up my docker environment. My Dockerfile looks like so

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

# Enable mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN /usr/bin/apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install git php5-dev libpcre3-dev gcc make graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick1-dev && \
/usr/bin/git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git && \
cd cphalcon/build/ && \
./install && \
echo 'extension=phalcon.so' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phalcon.ini && \

pecl -d preferred_state=beta install gmagick && \
echo 'extension=gmagick.so' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/gmagick.ini && \

cd /tmp && \
/bin/rm -rf /tmp/cphalcon/ && \
/usr/bin/apt-get -y purge git php5-dev libpcre3-dev gcc make libgraphicsmagick1-dev && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

which I got from this reference https://hub.docker.com/r/grahamwalters/php7-phalcon/, and my docker-compose.yml looks this this

```
php-docker-project:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8300:80"
  volumes:
    - ./public/:/var/www/html:rw
  environment:
    - TERM=xterm
```

My problem now is when I run the docker-compose up -d command, it doesn't install phalcon, but if I run the individual commands inside the container phalcon gets setup as expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: As a side note: have you noticed that Phalcon is now available as a package? https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/phalcon-on-packagecloud-io

Comment: You should provide the output of a `docker build .` and commands you use to check if phalcon is installed in the container.

Comment: Inspect logs.  Add debugging statements to dockerfile.  Determine exactly what "not installed" means.  What is happening and not happening?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fact that you don't have continuation markers on those blank lines makes it terminate on the first blank line?

Comment: Hi David, followed up on your suggestion, and that doesn't seem to be the issue.